# Why in swift we cannot adopt a protocol without inheritance a class from NSObject?

Tags: swift

If i use the following code it shows me error 
 "Type 'HttpConnection' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'"

```
class HttpConnection : NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
        var urlConnection       : NSURLConnection?
        weak var delegate       : HttpConnecting?

        init(delegate:HttpConnecting){
            self.delegate = delegate;
        }

        func startAsynRequestWithUrlString(url:NSString, withMethod:NSString){
        }
    }
```

If i subclass HttpConnection to NSObject then it works fine. So my question is when i need to adopt NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol in swift why i need to inherit the class from NSObject?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24991018/242933

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` itself inherits from `NSURLConnectionDelegate` which inherits from `NSObjectProtocol`.

That means that apart from implementing all the methods from `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, and `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, you also have to implement all the methods from `NSObjectProtocol` (e.g. equality, hash).

You didn't implement them, that's your mistake. If you inherit from `NSObject`, all that `NSObjectProtocol` methods are already implemented for you.

Comment: Thanks yes i seen that all the methods in NSObjectProtocol are required method :)

Answer (score 4):

Because in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) it says :

> The NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol describes methods that should
>   be implemented by the delegate for an instance of the NSURLConnection
>   class. Many methods in this protocol existed as part of an informal
>   protocol in previous versions of OS X and iOS.
>
> In addition to the methods described in this protocol, an
>   NSURLConnection delegate should also implement the methods described
>   in the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol.

and NSURLConnectionDelegate conforms to NSObject. Just make your class inherit from NSObject and you'll be good to go.