# How to make a class conform to a protocol in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

in Objective-C:

```
@interface CustomDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

in Swift:

```
class CustomDataSource : UITableViewDataSource {

}
```

However, an error message will appear:

1. Type 'CellDatasDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
2. Type 'CellDatasDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

What should be the correct way ?

Comment: The class name in your error messages doesn't seem to match up with your provided code?

Comment: Swift classes do not by default inherit from NSObject. They are their own base classes unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

> Type 'CellDatasDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

You have to make your class inherit from `NSObject` to conform to the `NSObjectProtocol`. Vanilla Swift classes do not. But many parts of `UIKit` expect `NSObject`s.

```
class CustomDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

}
```

But this:

> Type 'CellDatasDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Is expected. You will get the error until your class implements all required methods of the protocol.

So get coding :)

Comment: Thanks @Alex; you saved my day, since I've been struggling quite some time to get my Swift class conform to the UICollectionViewDataSource  protocol. Adding the NSObject inheritance in my Class solved it!

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks a compile warning was sufficient?

Comment: @Magoo Surely you meant insufficient. 'Does not conform to protocol' does not mean 'inherit from NSObject' to me.

Comment: @RoyFalk I mean a compile warning was sufficient over an error... You might not need to implement the entire protocol in all cases and might want to build prior to doing so... it's not a big deal, but feels a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

A class has to inherit from a parent class before conform to protocol. There are mainly two ways of doing it.

One way is to have your class inherit from `NSObject` and conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` together. Now if you want to modify the functions in the protocol, you need to add keyword `override` before the function call, like this

```
class CustomDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

However this sometimes gets your code messy because you may have many protocols to conform to and each protocol may have several delegate functions. In this situation, you can separate the protocol conforming code out from the main class by using `extension`, and you do not need to add `override` keyword in the extension. So the equivalent of the code above will be

```
class CustomDataSource : NSObject{
    // Configure the object...
}

extension CustomDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9, helps to implement all mandatory methods of Swift Datasource & Delegates.

Here is example of `UITableViewDataSource`:

Shows warning/hint to implement mandatory methods:

[image]

Click on 'Fix' button, it will add all mandatory methods in code:

[image]