# Swift : Type XXX must conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement a Swift class that must

1. Inherit from an Objective-C class
2. Implement a Objective-C protocol with class variable.

Although the Objective-C class I am subclassing is inheriting from NSObject, I receive the following compilation error :

`Type DDBItem  must conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'`

The Objective-C class and Objective-C protocol I am inheriting / implementing are available at 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/DynamoDB/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.h

AWSDynamoDBModel has a long chain of inheritance that eventually starts with NSObject
AWSDynamoDBModeling is enforcing two class variables.

My code is

```
class DDBItem : AWSDynamoDBModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

//    class var dynamoDBTableName : String { get { return "" }}
//    class var hashKeyAttribute  : String { get { return "" }}

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return ""
    }
    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Bonus Question : when trying to implement the Objective-C protocol mandated class variables as Swift  class variables, I receive a compilation error :

`Type DDBItem  must conform to protocol 'AWSDynamoDBModeling'`

Implementing them as function seems to be accepted.  Why ?

Comment: For the second question, property is just syntax sugar, when do bridging, I guess the compiler did the syntax sugar mapping for OC property to make them like property in Swift. BUT there is no class level property in OC, and the +() is a method, which the compiler just maps it to a swift class level method. It can only be called with A.classmethod().

Comment: For the first question, I have no clue on what is happened. Even you inherit from MTLModel which directly inherit from NSObject, the error still exists. Which means the deep nest is not the problem, but the MLTModel implementation.

Comment: Good point, I will have a look at MLTModel implementation

Comment: mmmh, inheriting directly from MTLModel works ... class DDBItem : MTLModel

Comment: but as soon as I am adding the protocol, the compilation error kicks in (Type must conform to NSObjectProtocol) even with "class DDBItem : NSOBject, AWSDynamoDBModeling {"

Comment: Yap, but if you use "class DDBItem: NSDictionary, AWSDynamoDBModeling{" It worked. So the error should locate in DDBItem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self answered for sake of archiving.

When adding

```
override func isEqual(anObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return super.isEqual(anObject)
}
```

to my class, it works.
This method should have been inherited from the base class.

Looks like a bug in Swift / Xcode 6.1 to me

Comment: I just tested this again with Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 and this is fixed!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991018/a-class-how-to-conform-to-protocol-in-swift Led me to a different answer: my class needed to add NSObject to the inheritance list

Comment: Inherit from NSObject which is a cleaner solution

Comment: As stated in my original question : "AWSDynamoDBModel has a long chain of inheritance that eventually starts with NSObject "

Comment: Seb, you answer isn't a general solution

Comment: and it's kind of cheating to accept your own answer while there's are way more popular one above urs

Comment: When I did that in 2014, it was the only answer.

Answer (score 79):

Just inherit from NSObject:

```
class DDBItem : NSObject, AWSDynamoDBModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
```

Comment: No, it is not the correct answer, because AWSDynamoDBModel already inherits from NSObject, as stated in my original question "AWSDynamoDBModel has a long chain of inheritance that eventually starts with NSObject"

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up for those that stumble upon this post. `AWSDynamoDBModeling` protocol has been changed in the latest SDK (v2.1.1). Required functions: 
`dynamoDBTableName` and `hashKeyAttribute` must be static. The documentation as of today (5/27/2015) appears to be out of date.

Example:

```
class Dingle:AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return "dev_coupons"
    }

    static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "status "
    }

    func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "post_date"
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return super.isEqual(object)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed! Write the functions this way:

```
static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {


    return "pb_Test"

}


static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {



    return "ID"
}
```

And you have to include this:

```
override func isEqual(anObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
   return super.isEqual(anObject)
}
```