# Swift How can I use AVAudioPlayerDelegate on a class that doesn't inherit AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, avaudioplayer

```
class myClass: AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    init(){
        player.delegate = self
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
          print("The song ended")
    }
}
```

I am learning Swift and trying to make a music playing app. I have custom class that has AVAudioPlayer object called **player** as its property. How can I use the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` methods with the **player** object?

When having the code like this I get the error:

> The type myClass does not conform to the protocol NSObjectProtocol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class does not conform NSObjectProtocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705591/class-does-not-conform-nsobjectprotocol)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inherit from NSObject.

```
class myClass: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    init(){
        player.delegate = self
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
          print("The song ended")
    }
}
```

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on the player.delegate = self line

Comment: Well, I guess that is a completely different question. Ask it in another question. I can't help, sorry. My guess is that AVAudioPlayer needs a file or something to be played before setting a delegate, or something similar. I have tried with 
        player = try? AVAudioPlayer.init(data: Data.init()) and now it is not crashing. My guess was correct. Add valid data to process and no error is made.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?